# Dropdown Hyphen and text. ex CSE - 123

Tags: html, forms

I need to design the form field like as

A drop-down list then a Hyphen then a text field so output will be

CSE - 123

I also store the data in database so there will be one name. if one name not possible then I can concat it.

But How can I design the field with a dropdown and hyphen and text field.

Help Me. Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Ee9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create select normally. But there is an issue with limiting the length of text field. So I added JavaScript for that.

```
<select name="course">
  <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
  <option value="EEE">EEE</option>
  <option value="HSS">HSS</option>
  <option value="ENG">ENG</option>
</select>
 - 
<input type="number" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==3) return false;">
```

Comment: Hi. But this is not in same align. I tried float left  but  not working. i think the - issue

Comment: Can you give me your sample desired output?

Comment: dropdown - textfield
in same line

Comment: I've put it in code pen. Can you check it out? https://codepen.io/jegatheesprana/pen/oNWyorY

Comment: that's great I have added some inline css I don't know when i used form-control class it having separate line

Comment: <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Course Code</label>
                <div class="form-group" >
                <select name="course_code_text" style="width:80px; padding:5px;border:1px solid silver;border-radius:5px;padding-bottom:9px;">
                    <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
                    <option value="EEE">SEEE</option>
                    <option value="HSS">HSS</option>
                    <option value="ENG">ENG</option>
                  </select>

Comment: -
                  <input type="text"  name="course_code_number" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==3) return false;" style="padding:5px;width:80px;border:1px solid silver;border-radius:5px;padding-bottom:9px;">
                </div>

Comment: $course_code = ($request->course_code_text) . '-' . ($request->course_code_number);
        dd($course_code);

Comment: in dd "ENG-123"